# How to extract database information from query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't seem to find the documentation laying this out clearly.

```
public function get_user_id_from_username($username){

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->select('id');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

}
```

Quite simply, I want to return the id that I have just selected from the database.
Can anyway tell me how I get access to that id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) was very enlightening

```
$row = $query->row();
echo $row->id;
```

Comment: The database section of the manual is quite large so I must have missed it, apologies for that, seems very simple now you've put it like that! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function get_user_id_from_username($username){
   $query='select id from users where username=?';
   $params=array();
   $params[]=$username;

   $result=$this->db->query($query, $params);
   $result=$result->row_array();
   return $result['id'];
}
```

if you're expecting multiple rows result_array works:

```
$result=$this->db->query($query, $params);
$result=$result->result_array();

//uses the form $result[0]['id'] 
//try a print_r
print_r($result);
```